# How to select all of the rows only with one checkbox in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, selection, selectall

I have a rich:extendeddatatable and I'm not using selection attribute to select rows.
Each row I have a checkbox but I want a general checkbox above the list to select all the rows.

When I clicked on the main checkbox, the other checkboxes in the datatable didn't selected.

Can somebody help with this? Thanks!  (I am not using js, it's pure java but nothing else)

I tried like this:

```
<div> 
   <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.status}" action="#{bean.checked}" />
</div>
```

And my function in the bean is like this:
Boolean selected=false;

```
public void checked(){
   if(this.selected){
     setSelected(false);
     selectAll(false); 
   }
   else{
    setSelected(true)
     selectAll(true);
   }
}
```

// and for selectAll() func. i'm setting my status value (which I assigned as a value to the checkbox in my datatable), also I am running that search query to rerender the extendeddatatable